# Does Python's interpreter compare values when allocating memory?

Tags: python, memory-management

I just watched this [informative video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6u5rhUQ6dU) on memory management in Python. In it, the presenter used the following code example (at about the 4:15 mark):

```
x = 300
y = 300
```

In this case, we have two names (`x` and `y`), each pointing at a value of 300. How did Python, when executing the `y = 300` line, know that it didn't need to allocate memory but rather increase the reference count, since memory for that value had already been allocated (through `x`)? Is the interpreter comparing values on each instantiation? If so, how does it keep track of the values it already knows about (I would assume it would do so using a `dict`)?

Suppose I introduced a new variable:

```
z = 100 + 200
```

Would `z` end up simply increasing the reference count to 300 once more?

When I try the following in my REPL (Python 3.6, Windows 7 x64), I get differing memory locations, which further confuses me (though, to be fair, she says not to try this in a REPL):

```
>>> x = 300
>>> y = 300
>>> print(id(x))
31191600
>>> print(id(y))
31191648
```

Comment: If I execute the example code on my machine and I call `id(x)` and `id(y)` to inspect the memory addresses of these two variables, I get two different results. If they are references to the same underlying C object, they should have the same memory address, should they not?

Comment: The video is misleading; Python makes no promises about whether any two uses of `300` use the same object. Depending on how you execute the code, it might end up making two objects.

Comment: I also get that result, @PeterWang (just edited my question to include that info). In the video, the presenter gets the same value. Perhaps she's using a different Python implementation than I am?

Comment: This behavior is relying on certain, implementation-specific optimizations that are not generalizable to objects in general. Suffice it to say, during compilation, the Python runtime can recognize certain immutable literals and only creates one object .